# KeyListener not working in JPanel?

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm trying to use a KeyListener in a java class but it's not accepting input for some strange reason. I just recently ran into this problem, and before it ran flawlessly but something changed and now it's not accepting any input. Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
public class SquarePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener, MouseListener
...
public SquarePanel {
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
    addKeyListener(this);
```

Then I go on to override keyPressed:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("SOMETHING");
}
```

Yet nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

(Side note: I think my program isn't receiving focus and that's the problem, because when I use `isFocusOwner()` it comes up false. If this is the case how do I fix this?)

Comment: Perhaps it s because you request the focus in the constructor, which is before it is actually added to any window. Check the return value of `requestFocusInWindow()` to see if it succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think my program isn't receiving focus and that's the problem,

That is the usual problem when a KeyListener doesn't work.

```
 this.requestFocusInWindow();
```

The above statement only works if the GUI is currently visible. Since you are executing the statement in the panel constructor it will have no effect. A component must be displayed on a visible GUI in order for a component to request focus.

You must request focus AFTER the GUI is visible.

Or, another option is to use the [RequestFocusListener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) .

Why are you use a KeyListener? Swing was designed to be used with [KY Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: I don't believe this is the case, because I added `System.out.println(this.isVisible())` before `this.setFocusable` and it outputted true. Also I'm not using key bindings because I'm uneducated :p thanks for the link

Comment: @aprogrammer, I said the GUI, not the panel, must be visible. All swing comonents are visible by default, except top level containers like JFrame, JDialog, JWindow.

Comment: okay, well i tried keybindings, and this is what I put in my constructor: `AbstractAction test = new AbstractAction() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          System.out.println("It worked!");
      }
  };
  getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("I"),
                              "test");
  getActionMap().put("test",
                               test);` and nothing happened

Comment: The panel still doesn't have focus (unless you fixed the problem like I suggested above). You used the wrong InputMap. The default InputMap is for when the component has focus. You need to use one of the other two InputMaps. If neither of the other two InputMapes don't work then you need to make sure the panel has focus, since you probably don't have any child components added to the panel, in which case you can go back to using the default InputMap. I can't give an exact answer because I have no details on what your GUI look like.